# Java multidimensional array layout

Tags: java, arrays

I am studying for an exam and this is about memory allocation of a multidimensional java array.

Given is the following code:

```
double [][] a = new double[4][];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     a[i] = new double[4-i];
```

I am supposed to draw the memory layout of this array, but I am afraid I don't fully comprehend how it even works.

It would also be very kind of you if you could show me how to print this array as list to the console so I can look at it. :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For the printing part, have a look at  Arrays.deepToString  : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EGbA.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EGbA.jpg) I am not sure if this answers your question. Above picture depicts how array elements will be stored in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to create new array in the for loop. Try this:

```
    double[][] a = new double[4][3];
```

Or you can initialize it in one statement like:

```
    double[][] a = {
        {1, 3, 2}, 
        {4, 5, 6}, 
        {7, 8, 9}
    };
```

And then print:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a))
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the syntax to me. That is very helpful. Unfortunately I had a little typo in the question body. It was supposed to be a[i] = new double [4 - i]. So each new row has one element less. But with your explanation on how to print the array I comprehended the layout. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since your array `a` is an *array* of *array* (**2D**) , you can use enhanced **for** loop to print elements.

So, your outer loop has `double[]` as type, and hence that declaration. If you iterate through your `a` in one more inner loop, you will get the type `double`.

```
     double[][] a = {
        {1, 3}, 
        {4, 5}, 
        {7, 8}
    };
List<Double> dou = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (double[] k: a) {
    for (double element: k) {
        dou.add(element) ;
    }

}
System.out.println(dou);
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Array memory layout]

I am not sure if this answers your question.

Above picture depicts how array elements will be stored in memory.

Comment: Hello, that is actually very helpful. Thank you for taking the time to draw it out for me. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to +1 you, but when I do I will come back and do it for you. :)

Comment: Thanks. Your comments speak themselves :)